# useFetch GET with body JSON

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am trying to hit my API endpoint with useFetch with the following code:

```
<script setup>
const token = "bearerToken000";
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
}

const { data: menus } = await useFetch('http://localhost:3001/api/stores/62989e35f5a66308effb63b5/vendables/menus', options)
</script>
```

This works fine for retrieving my data, but my API endpoint also accepts a body with the following object:

```
{
    "projection": ["title","description"]
}
```

Where you can specify the filter for the database query.
Works fine with POSTMAN, but using

```
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: {
            "projection": ["title","description"]
        }
    }
```

results in my endpoint never being reached and my return data is null.

Can anyone explain to me why and how I can send a GET request with a body using nuxt 3 useFetch or maybe different?

Comment: Try `data` rather than `body`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sending a JSON body you typically need to send a `POST` request rather than `GET`. There seems to be no issue with your code from what I can tell.

So have you tried:

```
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: {
            "projection": ["title","description"]
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I checked the source code for ohmyfetch which nuxt3 uses for requests.
It will only attach the body to the request if it's a payload method `'PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'`. So body is being ignored because you're using `GET`.
https://github.com/unjs/ohmyfetch/blob/f86917748e26d8e01e6c39c1e93ba4decf975972/src/fetch.ts#L112

Comment: I noticed, I guess I will have to use 
{{API}}/stores/{{storeId}}/vendables/menus?projection[]=title&projection[]=description&projection[]=enabled&projection[]=available

Like wth... why is the front-end doing this? It would be the server API's responsibility to either handle or disregard a body...
There is no standard that prohibits a GET request to send a body, so why is nuxt enforcing this?
I am the one building the API backend too.

Comment: The easiest solution would just be to change your backend and accept `POST` requests aswell. But maybe you can't do that for some reason. Another solution is to use `useAsyncData` and wrap your own request in there without ohmyfetch. Like axios or just a plain js request